# Image is not getting displayed in Microsoft Teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a bot where i have to display images in a bot. I have implemented the function and it is working fine for some images but somehow it doesn't work for a image with size 1.8 MB.

I tried the same on webchat and its working there but not in Teams.

[image: Image is not getting displayed in Teams]

[image: Same image getting displayed in webchat]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any image size restriction on Teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum 1024×1024 and 1 MB in PNG, JPEG, or GIF format; animated GIF are not supported

Answer (score 0):

Images must be httpS and must be anonymously accessible. They must also support TLS 1.2.